# Ajax запрос через https на тот же домен

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

.Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь осуществить ajax форму на своём сайте. Нашёл вот такой код:

```
   <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
      url = that.attr('action'),
      type = that.attr('method'),
      data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
      var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: type,
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
      });
    return false;
  });
});

</script>
```

Я перепробовал уже много других но везде в консоли пишет это: Заблокирована загрузка смешанного активного содержимого «http://putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/form1»
Как сделать POST запрос через https ??
Пробовал через datatype: "json" или "script" - не помогло.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Чтобы сделать запрос через https, его нужно делать через https, как не удивительно.

Если вас ничего больше не смущает в вашем js скрипте, то вам нужно обратить внимание каково именно поле action в вашей форме. Что такое datatype  тоже не очень понятно,  однако оно не имеет отношения вообще. Ajax посылает запрос на url который забирается из поля action формы. Именно там у вас скорее всего генерится адрес по протоколу http, а вам нужно https, раз уж у вас сайт на https.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В action прописан путь через https

Comment: Посмотрите что выдает console.log(url = that.attr('action')); например. Точно ли там https  ?

Comment: И вообще присмотритесь к скрипту. Вы должны помнить что в данной версии JS   у переменных  var  область видимости внутри всей функции одна, т.е. по идее у вас вот этот that перезаписывается и не очень понятно вообще как все работает. Хотя я могу конечно ошибаться.

Comment: Подставил код, в консольке пишет undefined.

Comment: Попробую этот скрпт поставить:

Comment: `код`
        <script>
          function call() {
            var msg   = $('#country').serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'https://putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/form1.php/',
              data: msg,
              success: function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
              },
              error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
              }
            });

          }
        </script>`код`

Comment: Пишет [ссылка](https://i.imgur.com/USzrY5c.jpg)

Comment: Добавьте в $.ajax параметр crossdomain: true.  Мне помогло.